# The record couldn’t be saved because it failed to trigger a flow - Process Builder

Tags: apex, trigger, flow, process-builder

I have one Process Builder which helps me to do certain things on my Opportunity create/update and all.

Now, the problem is I have written one Trigger on Opportunity which is expected to run "After Update" while checking certain conditions and business logic following the same.

Check out the following Screenshot - for more detailed error message.

[image]

Any Suggestions ? or help ?

I have found following as [Known Issue 1](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XMLAA2)    and [Known Issue 2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72951/process-builder-breaking-production-deployments). This might help to answer.

Updated Question :

> My Trigger is also getting called too many times where I found
>   Trigger.new() = Null

**Debug Logs**

> 08:43:49.437 (5437733373)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[37]|System.DmlException:
>   Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, The record couldn’t be saved because it
>   failed to trigger a flow. 
> A flow trigger failed to execute the
>   flow with version ID 301110000000ZDe. 
>  Contact your administrator
>   for help.: []
>
> 08:43:49.439 (5439388332)|FATAL_ERROR|System.DmlException: Insert
>   failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER, The record couldn’t be saved because it
>   failed to trigger a flow. 
> A flow trigger failed to execute the
>   flow with version ID 301110000000ZDe. 
>  Contact your administrator
>   for help.: []

Comment: does your process invokes any apex methods which makes any callouts? Also, did you check the debug logs to know what is causing the process to fail.

Comment: No I didn't made any Apex Method or Callouts, I will look into debug logs again, I did once but didn't found anything to notice.

Comment: Hope you have set the debug log level for workflow to Finer. If not, please set it and post the log as well here, if you can. - Mani

Comment: could you add snippets of your code,also what you process does on insert/update. Since, you have mentioned that trigger is getting called too many times, most probably your triggers are getting recursivley called.

Comment: Can you move your trigger code into your Process Builder Flow using invokable methods?

Comment: Problem is that if there is Process builder on DML, that start flow -- debug logs are not displayed for that flow, it only says that there is an exception. So, to grab a normal debug logs -- try to launch flow manually, with input parameters as in process builder. In that case, debug logs would be presented

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the procees builder is getting NULL values for any field on opportunity [ lookup or any other ]. Provide legitimate value; it will work...!

There is always a missing value in process builder which brings this exception.

Thanks...!

Answer (score 1):

We do get this error while working with flow.For more details you can go to this link:https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008Xn7AAE

Thanks 
Himanshu

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem recently and decided to leave an answer.

There is a [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000230650&language=en_US) about this error is case of a Data Loader. It basically says:

> While Process Builder is being improved to better handle bulk processing, it can still generate errors when a large Data Loader Insert or Upsert triggers a Process.

And their resolution is... To set the batch size smaller!

> Within Data Loader, navigate to Settings>Settings and lower the Batch size to "1".
>
> This will perform the update in smaller chunks, and allow Process Builder the timings required to complete the actions.  This will cause only a minimal impact on update times for the Data Loader process.
>
> Note: Some environments may support slightly larger Batch sizes like "20" without errors but, if the error persist with "20" the batch should be set to "1".

---

For your case it might be that you are in a loop that where a trigger and the process builder are invoking each other