# Unit tests dependent on Process Builder record creation failing

Tags: unit-test, process-builder

I have 2 process builder (PB) flows:
The first creates 3 record in a custom object when a new quote is created.

The second creates a new custom object (same object as first PB flow) record when a quote field is updated by a trigger on the custom object.

in Unit tests I create a quote, and the first flow fires and produces the 3 records in the custom object I am expecting. Brilliant.

However, when I update the field to fire the trigger in the custom object, the second flow doesn't seem to react - at least not quick enough to allow the unit test to realise.

Testing manually and everything works fine. Any ideas why this might be and how I might mitigate the problem/delay?

Comment: did you look at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72951/process-builder-breaking-production-deployments ?

Comment: I did see that question, but discounted it because I am not calling an invocable method anywhere.

Comment: Did you get any answer for this?